# How to select second element between multiple identical classname?

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I have a structure like this:

```
<div class="test">
    <span>one</span>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <span>two</span>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <span>three</span>
</div>
```

And here is my code:

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=test]') as $article) {
    echo $type .= $article->find('span',0)->plaintext."<br>";
}
```

And here is current result:

```
one
two
three
```

And here is expected result:

```
two
```

How can I do that?

---

**Note:** I use [this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) PHP library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = $html->find('div[class=test]', 1);
echo $type .= $data->find('span',0)->plaintext."<br>";
```

That should print what you want as 1 is the second `div` element to select (starts at 0 so first one = 0, 2nd = 1).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look into my package [PHPHTMLQuery](https://github.com/AbdelilahLbardi/phphtmlquery).

After installation using composer you can do the same like this:

```
$content= '<div class="test">'.
    '<span>one</span>'.
'</div>'.
'<div class="test">'.
    '<span>two</span>'
'</div>'.
'<div class="test">'.
    '<span>three</span>'.
'</div>';

$document = new AbdelilahLbardi\PHPHTMLQuery\Getter($content);

$elements = $document->withTag('div')
                     ->withClass('test')
                     ->select();

foreach($elements as $element){
    var_dump($element);
}
```